# Reactor - using Flux.publish() prevents StepVerifier.thenCancel() from working?

Tags: java, project-reactor

If I use my flux directly with `StepVerifier` things work fine, but if I call `publish().autoConnect()` on the flux and use the result with `StepVerifier` then the `verify()` step never completes.

E.g. I have a simple flux like this that generates the integers 0 to infinity:

```
Flux<Integer> flux = Flux.fromStream(Stream.iterate(0, i -> i + 1));
```

Then everything works fine with `StepVerifier` if I just consume a few elements, cancel and verify:

```
StepVerifier.create(flux)
    .thenConsumeWhile(i -> i < 10)
    .thenCancel()
    .verify();
```

But if instead, I do the following then it never finishes:

```
StepVerifier.create(flux.publish().autoConnect())
    .thenConsumeWhile(i -> i < 10)
    .thenCancel()
    .verify();
```

I'm guessing there's something fairly obvious going on here but I don't know what?

This crops up as I'm trying to use `StepVerifier` in a test with an API that looks something like this:

```
class MyApi {
    private Flux<Integer> underlyingFlux = ...

    Flux<Integer> getFlux() { return underlyingFlux.publish().autoConnect(); }
}
```

---

See my [github examples](https://github.com/george-hawkins/publish-cancel-test/tree/master/src/test/java/com/example) for some ready to run code that demonstrates the issues I've seen with `StepVerifier`.

---

**Update:** this issue was accepted as a bug by the Reactor team - see issue [#1528](https://github.com/reactor/reactor-core/issues/1528) - and a fix is available in version 3.2.9.RELEASE of reactor-core.

Comment: It is not about the publish() method. When I tried like that  StepVerifier.create(flux.publish()).thenCancel().verify() it is still working. It is about the autoConnect(). You are connecting again and again. It does not end.

Comment: So is there no way to use `StepVerifier` with such a flux? Without looking into the implementation of the API I can't see if a returned flux has had `autoConnect()` called on it or not.

Comment: @haticeSigirci - I don't think `autoConnect()` is about automatically _reconnecting_, it's about connecting to the upstream flux once one has enough subscribers. I've added a `thenConsumeWhile` step to my examples - this requires a subscription (which wouldn't happen without `autoConnect()`) and I've added a link to a GitHub repo that demonstrates things by way of a few tests.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue was accepted as a bug by the Reactor team - see issue [#1528](https://github.com/reactor/reactor-core/issues/1528) - and a fix is available in version 3.2.9.RELEASE of reactor-core.